# What is an adjective to describe what this baby is doing?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, gestures

I was saving [an animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTwbi.gif) (over 2MB in size) to my PC, but couldn't think of what to name it. After a few minutes of staring at [some adjective]baby.gif I figured I'd put it to you guys.

I was reaching for something along the lines of "profoundly contemplating", but it's in a kind of scenery-chewing sort of way. Is there a word to describe this? Obviously it's a silly gif of a baby that doesn't know what it's doing, but adults/actors do this as well. What's a good adjective to describe this kind of gesturing?

Comment: It's part of the normal development of an infant to learn and understand what it can do with its arms and hands, how far they can reach. I don't think there is any intention in that movement, the baby is only playing and the vídeo keeps repeating the same scene. On the other hand, it might be some act the baby has been encouraged to repeat and it does it whenever the right cue is given.

Comment: Maybe he's pulling over a fast one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He looks like he's ***scheming***, to me.

Comment: I really like scheming. I think that's closest to what I was looking for. How could you also imply an exaggerated gesture like that as well? "Conspicuously scheming" or "connivingly stroking his chin" maybe?

Answer (score 1):

He's (she's?) a practicing Jedi: *[These are not the Droids you're looking for](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/quotes?item=qt0440731)*.

Answer (score 0):

How about pondering? It looks like the baby is thinking deeply about something, expecially with the chin-rubbing and lowered eyebrows.

> ponder: to consider something deeply and thoroughly; meditate

[(Source)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ponder)

Answer (score 0):

That's clearly *plotting* by a martial artist genius.